# dotNet Core: No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

This is the stack error that appears.

[image]

How can I fix?

**Update**

This is my EmployeesContext.cs file:

```
namespace SDV.Fabio.DotNetCore.ConnectingToMySQL.MailTrapApplication
{


public class EmployeesContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeesContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeesContext> options)
    : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(b => b.MessageId)
            .HasColumnName("message_id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(b => b.Date)
            .HasColumnName("date");

    }

    public DbSet<Employee> email_logs { get; set; } //DbSet<modello> NomeTabella
}
}
```

My model is Employee and the table in database is called email_logs with two columns: message_id and date

Comment: Where can be the error?

Comment: Resolved! I changed the type of the property model from datetime to string

Comment: using strings to work with data is no free lunch, Just be warned: it's not a long term, and definitely not production ready code.